# How to differentiate multivariable calculus with parametric equations?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

> $u=u(x,y)$ and $x=e^s\cos t, y=e^s\sin t$

How do I work with this type of multivariable calculus?

E.g. how do I find $u_{ss}$, $u_{tt}$, $u_{xx}$ etc?

I don't know where to start exactly, I had a few attempts but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple (in theory…): the chain rule for multivariable functions yields
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \\
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial s^2}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\biggl(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\biggr)\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\biggl(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\biggr)\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}
\end{align}
&c. &c.

Comment: Hi, thanks. How exactly do I find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$?  Also when finding e.g. $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}$ do I treat t as an independent variable?

Comment: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ depends on how $u$ is defined. It's the ordinary partial derivative w.r.t. the 1st variable. As to $t$, a priori, yes, it is an independent variable